# Where does Ubuntu store the name shown in the authentication window?

Tags: authentication, 21.10

I want to change my PC name in Ubuntu 21.10.
I edited:

- `/etc/hostname`
- `/etc/hosts`

and rebooted. Now I can find my PC using the new name and also the prompt shows it correctly.

But when it requires an authentication, i.e. when you want to install new updates from the GUI, a popup dialog appears asking the password. In this popup the name displayed is the older one.

**Where does Ubuntu store the name shown in this authentication dialog?**

EDIT:

I thought there was only one authentication popup dialog. Anyway, I'm talking about this one:

[image]

Comment: A screenshot of the _authentication dialog_ will be helpful. Is it the user name or the host name?

Comment: @FedKad question updated with the requested screenshot. On my personal PC the displayed name is my full name, not user name.

Comment: Perhaps I found it under Settings > Users > pencil icon to edit the name

Comment: @Mark You have found the correct answer. You may want to answer your own question and convert your comment to an answer. Then accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it under Settings > Users and use the pencil icon to edit the name details.

Answer (score -1):

The way to change the name via the GUI is to navigate to `Settings > Users`. This menu will allow you to edit the user name.

Comment: The question is not about the device name. The question is about the **name of the user**. So this answer is wrong. I am down voting your answer. If you correct your answer I will remove the down vote.

Comment: @user68186 Ah, my fault. Totally misread it. I've edited it, though the answer was already taken care of above.

Comment: I have removed my down vote. However there is another one that I don't have any control over. You may want to delete the answer to get rid of the negative vote. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, amigo. I think I'll leave it up to show other newcomers what NOT to do.